# react-native: <TextInput/> remove keyboard predictions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a `<TextInput/>` react native component here. When I begin typing in it, I see the predictions box above the keyboard. I don't want this to show up, how can I get rid of this?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

```
<TextInput
placeholder="email"
autoCapitalize="none"
keyboardType="email-address"
placeholderTextColor="white"
style={styles.input}
onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
value={this.state.email}
/>
```

[image: keyboard]

Comment: What happens if you turn autoCorrect to false? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autocorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using `<TextInput autoCorrect={false} />` for disabling suggestions.